# How do I determine the curve of the transmission output on a torque-angular velocity graph for a DC motor?

Tags: motor, torque, velocity

I'm doing a homework problem that involves motor characteristic graphs. For this problem, I have a motor with stall torque of 8 N-cm and a no-load angular velocity of 80 rad/s. The motor powers a 4-wheel drive robot that requires an input of 60 N-cm from the motor to power all the wheels. Additionally, the robot has a transmission with a gear ratio R = 20 and is frictionless.

I need to find the point where the transmission output line intersects the horizontal "wheel requirement" line (= 60 N-cm) so that I can find the velocity of the robot at this point (called the operating point).

The issue I'm having is that I don't know the equation of the transmission line. All I know is that the \$t(0) = t_s\$ (read as "torque at angular velocity of 0 rad/s = stall torque"), \$t(w_n) = 0\$ (read as "torque at no-load speed = 0 N-cm"), and that \$t(w_i) = 60 \$ N-cm (read as "torque at angular velocity of interest = 60 N-cm"). Once I know the stall torque and no-load speed of the transmission output line, I can figure out the equation of the line and the angular velocity at the operating point.

Comment: R=20 means for each revolution of the motor the transmission revolves 72 degrees with 20 times the torque (no losses because frictionless). So the new torque-velocity chart will pass 1600cm on torque axis and 20 rad/sec on velocity axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer to the question at [Understanding D.C. Motor Characteristics](http://lancet.mit.edu/motors/motors3.html).

What you are missing in this problem is the curve between Torque and Speed that you can find at section 3.1.

The maximum torque is \$T=8 Ncm\$ (with the gear ratio - \$T_r=160 Ncm\$) and the no load velocity is \$w = 80rad/s\$ (with the gear ratio \$w_r=2rad/s\$). You need to find \$T_f=60 Ncm\$ and the formula is:

$$T_f = T_r - w_f \cdot \frac{T_r}{w_r}$$

where \$w_f\$ is your angular velocity where the torque is \$60Ncm\$